# equivalent of Observable.of that emits and error

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

Is there an equivalent of `Observable.of(something)`  that would emit `something` as an error ?
In other words, it would return an Observable that does `observer.error(something)` instead of `observable.next(something)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `Observable.throw()` static method that creates an Observable that only send the `error` notification.

```
Observable.throw(new Error('Everything is broken!'))
```

See: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-throw